# how to trigger onchange event for default selected radio button value

Tags: jquery

I have radio button field and it has default selected value, so how to trigger on change event without changing any radio button value when page loads. In my app I need to disable few dropdowns based on default selected radio button value

Comment: please provide sample html and javascript code

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript; I think that covers the same ground.

Answer (score 1):

you can use do like...

> when page loads

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

//On page load, here you can check your radio button value
var val= $('input[name=name_of_your_radiobutton]:checked').val();

//on the basis of val you can add logic
dowork()

});
```

You can put your common logic into some function...

```
function dowork()
{
  //put your common logic here
}
```

Now you can call this method(dowork) on both event(Page Load and Radio Button change event)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but am looking for something to write common functions for both page loads and radio button selected or changed